# Spring Cloud Data Flow - relaunch/retry Composed Task from the middle

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a Composed Task in Spring Cloud Data Flow server as below:
[image]

If `task-b` produces the exit message as `FAIL` then it will execute `task-d` and end the flow.
I would like to retry this job/composed-task from `task-b` again once the issue was fixed so that it can follow the next path to `task-c`. There is some large processing done as a part of `task-a` and I want to avoid repeating this task again.

When I try to launch the `task-b` from 'Task execution' tab, it only ran `task-b` and then stopped.
From 'Job executions' section, I cannot see any option to retry the job/composed-task from `task-b`.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

@adesai Thank you for question.
In the scenario that you present, this Composed Task Runner launch is considered successful since it had an option to take if `Task-b` "Failed" namely to launch `Task-d`.  Thus it can't be restarted, since it was successful.
One option is to suggest adding a feature to composed task runner that would allow you to specify a comma delimited list of tasks that it should skip.  Something like `composed-task-runner.skip-steps=task-a`.
You could open an issue on data flow for this, if this feature would be useful.

Comment: Regarding `task-b` successful status, I have made `task-b` failed with `ERROR` as a final status as well. And fixing `task-b` and retrying it, has the same outcome where it doesn't execute the next steps (`task-c` or  `task-d`).

Comment: CTR doesn't know you executed task-b by itself. CTR only tracks the tasks it launched.